# Confirm order in open cart

Tags: php, opencart

How the confirm order in opencart works.
I am facing problem. When I click on confirm order, the page is not getting redirected. 
In the file `\upload\catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\confirm.tpl` and on line number 53 there is a variable `$payment`. I want to know where this variable is defined.

Comment: really? Please post some code, so we have something to work on

Answer (score 3):

The order confirmation in OpenCart works this way:

1. during the checkout process a customer selects his preffered payment method
2. when on confirm tab, a new temp order is created in DB
3. after clicking on "Confirm" button, finally a payment method's `confirm()` method is called which confirms the order (may other steps depending on payment method selected be taken before order is finally confirmed)
4. after all the customer is redirected to `checkout/success` page

Variable $payment should be defined and initialized after the payment method is selected, check the `catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php` on line 382 (if not modified).

This is not quite a question for a SO, You should be able to get through the code for yourself and only ask here for a concrete problem you might have. Your question is not a real question for SO, maybe just a non-swimmer shout in the dark water...